# how to get quick list of customization in peoplesoft

Tags: customization, peoplesoft

how to get quick list of customization in peoplesoft with their description, compare reports are bulky ,
My attempt is to execute below sql to get list of records which we need to query.

```
 SELECT 'SELECT '''
 ||'RecDescr.'
 ||A.RECDESCR
 ||'-Record.'
 ||A.RECNAME
 ||'.FieldName.'
 ||d.COLS1
 ||'->'
 ||'''||'
 ||B.FIELDNAME||','||d.COLS1
 ||', COUNT(1) OVER() AS CNT_OF_OBJECTS1 FROM '
 || DECODE(SUBSTR(B.recname, 1,2),'PS','','PS_')
 ||A.RECNAME
 || ' WHERE LASTUPDOPRID <> ''PPLSOFT'';' as Details
 —, B.RECNAME, B.FIELDNAME, A.RECDESCR
 FROM PSRECDEFN A,
 PSRECFIELDALL B ,
 (SELECT TABLE_NAME ,
 LISTAGG (COLUMN_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
 ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID) AS COLS1
 FROM USER_TAB_COLS
 WHERE column_id<4
 GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
 ) d
 WHERE ( A.RECNAME = B.RECNAME
 AND A.OBJECTOWNERID = 'PPT')
 AND A.RECTYPE =0
 AND b.recname IN
 (SELECT DISTINCT recname FROM PSRECFIELDALL c WHERE FIELDNAME='LASTUPDOPRID'
 )
 AND A.RECNAME NOT LIKE '%AUD%'
 AND b.FIELDNAME LIKE '%DESC%'
 AND (DECODE(SUBSTR(B.recname, 1,2),'PS','','PS_')
 ||A.RECNAME=d.TABLE_NAME)
 ORDER BY B.RECNAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two straight forward ways to get to the answer.  The first is the most accurate.

1. Go into AppDesigner and choose Tools->Compare and Report->To Database.  Give a project name (say CUSTOMOBJECTS) and then compare to your PUM Image or Demo database. I chose to compare to LM92U018.

Under options, choose Compare Type of "Database" and say OK. Then click "Compare".  This takes a while to run. At the end, you can run the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PSPROJECTITEM 
WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'CUSTOMOBJECTS' 
AND SOURCESTATUS IN (4, 5)
```

This will give you the complete list of all of your custom objects.  If you want to get a pretty report, you can use something like this:

https://peoplesofttutorial.com/sql-to-list-project-items-in-peoplesoft/

2. A query just to pull table names, similar to the one you were writing, is this:

   ```
    SELECT A.RECNAME
    FROM PSRECDEFN A
    JOIN PSRECFIELDALL B
    ON B.RECNAME = A.RECNAME
    AND B.FIELDNAME = 'LASTUPDOPRID'
    WHERE A.RECTYPE = 0
    AND A.SQLTABLENAME <> ' '
    AND A.RECNAME LIKE 'PS%'
   ```

This should limit you to the actual tools tables you are interested in.